# How to display time like hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds:microseconds?

Tags: java

Is there any way to display time upto microseconds precision using LocalDateTime in java? Like we used in SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:S");
```

Similarly, what should I do if I want to display like this: `hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds:microseconds`
I read it can be done using LocalDateTime. But how?

Comment: You want a colon between milliseconds and microseconds??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ISO 8601

Your desired format for a time-of-day is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating String representations of their date-time values.

## Nanoseconds

The java.time classes support a resolution up to nanoseconds. The legacy date-time classes they supplant were limited to milliseconds.

## `LocalTime`

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Determining the current time-of-day does require a time zone. For any given moment, the time-of-day varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z );
```

Generate a String by calling `toString`.

```
String output = lt.toString();  // 12:34:56.789
```

In Java 8, capturing the current time is limited to milliseconds. The class can hold up to nanoseconds, but the `Clock` implementation has legacy limitations. In Java 9, a new `Clock` implementation is capable of capturing the current time in up to nanoseconds (depending on the host computer’s hardware capability).

The Question mentions `LocalDateTime`. That class is for a date-time, a date plus a time-of-day. But the class purposely lacks any concept of time zone. Almost never what you want, as a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. Without the context of a time zone saying "3 PM on Jan 15th this year" has no meaning as 3 PM in Paris Texas is not the same as in Montréal Québec which is not the same as in Auckland New Zealand. Assign a time zone (`ZoneId`) to determine an actual moment in a `ZonedDateTime` object. For UTC values, just use `Instant`.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` will do you what you want. See the javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

The codes appear to be the same as they were with `SimpleDateFormat`, so the same format string "HH:mm:ss:S" will continue to work.

Comment: if I want to display microseconds, "HH:mm:ss:S - this is upto milliseconds only", how microseconds will be displayed?

Comment: No, the formatting pattern codes in `DateTimeFormatter` are similar to the codes in `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Last I read, java 8 can do nanoseconds as per documentation here... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html - I heard java 9 will have some major updates to date and time features.

Comment: Java 8 already had major updates to date/time features... hopefully they won't immediately do another such update!

Comment: Java 9 brings fixes and minor features to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Java7**

If you use a [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) Object then you can use the normal formatting for the `Date` part and then append `":" + timestamp.getNanos ();` to get a nano second formatting String